# Obfuscating flutter module/package

Tags: flutter, dart, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate my custom flutter module/package, can't find any relevant information. Please help me out.

I have a custom package, and i want to obfuscate it before using it somewhere else, got some article but they are only showing to obfuscate the flutter app which i dont want.